# In VIM how can I configure ctrl-v to enter visual blockmode while in insert mode?

Tags: vim

My Google skills failed me.  I thought this would be an old, well worn question.

In VIM input mode, how do I get `<c-v>` to be recognized as if I were in Normal mode, i.e. enter visual blockwise mode?

I tried a `noremap! <C-v <ESC>:visual block`, but that obviously isn't quite the right set of magic words.

**NOTE:** changed "edit mode" to "insert mode" as suggested by @Explosion's comment.

Comment: @Explosion Pills assumes that by "edit mode" you mean "insert mode," and my guess is that he is right.  It will help if you refer to vim's modes by their standard names:  `:help vim-modes`.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I. Couldn't remember the correct name nor how to look it up.  Vi is so unlike ANY other editor and so unintuitive that it still amazes me that I use it and even like the function most of the time.

Comment: That's not a bad idea as far as easily getting into visual-block mode...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you want is `inoremap`, which maps in insert mode.  You can just use `<C-v>` since it is not remapped.

```
inoremap <C-v> <Esc><C-v>
```